# Simple Security setup on WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, security

Im currently in the process of exposing our internal CRM system to the web so our employees can use it outside out network. The data is being surfaced to our web application via asp.net WebAPI.

We have SSL setup on the website. But am thinking how else I can make sure the WebAPI is secure from malicious use. My ideas are:

1. Tracking what IP addresses are accessing the WebAPI and only allow addresses that we have validated are from employees. Problem with this having dynamic IP addresses we might be constantly updating a data store of valid IP addresses.
2. The user has to login to the system. So every request to the webapi will send across their login details which will be validated before the webapi will process any request.
3. Pass the device ID of the device using the webAPI and validate (pretty much the same as IP Address tracking in idea 1)
4. Having a unique clientside generated access token which much match up at the server side.

Has anybody got any advice on my security ideas I outlined? Is it to little or is it overkill?

Just want to make sure the data cannot be hacked, because my butt would be on the line if it did.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would actually choose a totally different solution - updating valid dynamic IP's will be hell.

I would:

1. Create a new Project using the "Intranet Application" instead of using "Internet Application"
2. Host the application on your local office network
3. Set up VPN to your Office for your colleagues

Would this solution be possible for you?

Comment: I want a simple connection. We have a lot of people out on the road, so having them access the site through a vpn will be a bit of a nightmare with whatever device they are using and also will slow down the application